# How to limit / offset query that returns several rows per unique ID?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, group-by, limit

My issue is that I need to paginate data from this query:

```
function search($search_term, $limit, $offset)
{
    $id = $this->auth->get_user_id();

    $query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT user_id,
           first_name,
           cars_name,
           cars_id
    FROM   user_profiles
           LEFT JOIN cars
             ON cars.id_fk = user_id
    WHERE  user_id NOT LIKE '$id'
           AND activated = 1
           AND banned = 0
           AND first_name LIKE '%$search_term%'
    ORDER BY first_name ASC
    ");

    $search_data = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

        $search_data[$row->user_id]['name'] = $row->first_name;
        $search_data[$row->user_id]['cars'][$row->cars_id] = array(
                'cars_name' => $row->cars_name);
    }
    return $search_data;
}
```

A sample data table / query response would be:

```
1   JOE   HONDA    123
1   JOE   TOYOTA   124
2   MAC   VW       125
2   MAC   HONDA    126
2   MAC   TESLA    127
3   STU   SUBARU   128
3   STU   KIA      129

-----------
Page 1
-----------
1   JOE   HONDA   123
          TOYOTA  124

2   MAC   VW      125
          HONDA   126

------------
Page 2
------------
3    STU    SUBARU  128
            KIA     129
```

If I enter a limit and offset at the end of MySQL query

```
...
LIMIT $limit
OFFSET $offset;
");
```

the limit and offset are applied to the **total** number of rows, not the the number of rows grouped by user.

I've tried using `GROUP BY` but was unable to make it work.

My goal is to make the query as above but LIMIT and OFFSET the query by a number of rows that counts users, not **all** rows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do this in one query. My solution would be to get the count of unique ID's using a group by query with the same parameters:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS uid_count
FROM   user_profiles
       LEFT JOIN cars
         ON cars.id_fk = user_id
GROUP BY user_profiles.user_id
WHERE  user_id NOT LIKE '$id'
       AND activated = 1
       AND banned = 0
       AND first_name LIKE '%$search_term%'
```

Then fetch the <strike>uid_count</strike>`mysql_num_rows` and use that to calculate pagination variables for the above query.

Comment: thanks @mel - i think one issue with that approach is that if the number of user-rows is say `3` (as in my example above), when I LIMIT or OFFSET the second query using `3` it will not work because the row structure is different

Answer (score 0):

The solution really is to use a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
       user_id,
       first_name,
       cars_name,
       cars_id
FROM   user_profiles
       LEFT JOIN cars
         ON cars.id_fk = user_id
WHERE  user_id NOT LIKE '$id'
       AND activated = 1
       AND banned = 0
       AND first_name LIKE '%$search_term%'
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY first_name ASC
LIMIT 100
```

The order is important. `GROUP BY` first, then `ORDER BY`, and then `OFFSET`/`LIMIT`.

Notice the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` up there? After the query has executed, if you want to get the total row count (including those who aren't returned because of the `LIMIT` clause), just use:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `count`
```

And fetch the `count` column.

However, like you said, the rows will collapse and you will lose some `cars_name` and `cars_id` values.

Another solution is to use GROUP_CONCAT, then split it in PHP:

```
SELECT 
       user_id,
       first_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(cars_name SEPARATOR ','),
       GROUP_CONCAT(cars_id SEPARATOR ','),
FROM   user_profiles
       LEFT JOIN cars
         ON cars.id_fk = user_id
WHERE  user_id NOT LIKE '$id'
       AND activated = 1
       AND banned = 0
       AND first_name LIKE '%$search_term%'
ORDER BY first_name ASC
LIMIT 100
```

This would give you something like:

```
1   JOE   HONDA,TOYOTA     123,124
2   MAC   VW,HONDA,TESLA   125,126,127
3   STU   SUBARU,KIA       128,129
```

Comment: thanks @netcoder - will the group by prevent me from building that multi array below the query? i need access to the vars deeper in the array and i wonder if `group by` is going to collapse the rows

Comment: @torr: Updated the answer. Dunno if it'll help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list like this

```
Page 1
----------------------
1   JOE   HONDA    123
1   JOE   TOYOTA   124

Page 2
----------------------
2   MAC   VW       125
2   MAC   HONDA    126
2   MAC   TESLA    127

Page 3
----------------------
3   STU   SUBARU   128
3   STU   KIA      129
```

Forget about limit, do this instead:

A - First retrieve a list of user id's and insert that into a temp table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test`.`temp_user_ids` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = MEMORY
```

B - Next insert the relavant user_id's into the table.

```
INSERT INTO temp_user_ids
  SELECT null, user_id
FROM   user_profiles
       LEFT JOIN cars
         ON cars.id_fk = user_id
WHERE  user_id NOT LIKE '$id'
       AND activated = 1
       AND banned = 0
       AND first_name LIKE '%$search_term%'
ORDER BY user_id DESC  /*insert in reverse order !*/
```

The lowest user_id is the last_insert_id in the temptable, and the temp_table
items are in sequential order.

C - Set the SQL @var @current_id to the last_insert_id in the temp_table.

```
SELECT @current_id:= LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

D - Next select relevant rows from the table, using only the user_id you want.

```
SELECT count(*) as row_count,
       up.user_id,
       first_name,
       group_concat(cars_name) as car_names,
       group_concat(cars_id) as car_ids,
FROM   user_profiles up
       LEFT JOIN cars
         ON cars.id_fk = up.user_id
       INNER JOIN temp_user_ids t 
         ON (t.user_id = up.user_id)
WHERE  t.id = @current_id
GROUP BY up.user_id
ORDER BY cars.id
```

E - Now lower the @current_id

```
SELECT @current_id:= @current_id - 1;
```

F - And repeat step D and E until there's no more rows to be had.

The first field `row_count` tells you the number of rows aggregated in the fields
`car_names` and `car_ids`. You can separate these fields by using php's `explode`.

Comment: thanks for your response - I updated the OP with the actual structure I need -- it's a bit different from what you show - would this require changes to your code?